# Spark - Getting an element after a try call and sucess

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
val isGroup =
  Try(groupPower(Doc.productType.id),
      .contains(Doc.powerGroup.id,doc2.Doc.pOrdernum)).getorElse(0)
```

I understand the code above with `contains` assigns a boolean to the `isGroup` val. However, I want the pOrdernum or int upon success and 0 int upon on failing the `contains` statement, thus the `.getorElse(0)` statement at the end.

How would I be able to accomplish this? I just need the value or second element that it is checking against if it's a success(returns true) assign the value pOrdernum which is an int to the isgroup val

Comment: please update with groupPower function and the case classes .

Comment: I don't get it, does groupPower throw an exception? Do you really need try-catch here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to do something like this:

```
   val result:Int =
      Try{
        groupPower(Doc.productType.id).contains(Doc.powerGroup.id,doc2.Doc.pOrdernum)
        doc2.Doc.pOrdernum
      }.getorElse(0)
```

The result of contains (i.e. an boolean) is now thrown away. If no exception occurs, `doc2.Doc.pOrdernum` is returned